# AngularJS refresh controller when factory value updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently I am using a factory to pass a value between two controllers. However I am unsure of how to make the second one update when the first one passes in a value. How should I go about this? My controllers look like

```
app.factory('fact', function(){
  return{
    data: {
      begin: '',
      end: ''
    },
    update: function(first, last){
      this.data.begin = first;
      this.data.end: '';
    }
  };
});

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, fact){
  fact.update(10, 12);
});

app.controller('secCtrl', function($scope, $http, fact){
  $http.get("website" + begin + end);
});
```

Comment: first of all you need: `$http.get("website" + fact.data.begin + fact.data.end);` and it's best to put `$http` call in a function that you can call on some events, if something changes in a factory you can broadcast an event with `$rootScope.$broadcast("data_updated");` and respond with `$rootScope.$on("data_updated", your_function_with_http_callback);`

Comment: Is there a way to not use $rootScope?

Comment: it's similar to an event listener, which pure js would use instead; you can also try to use `$scope.$on(...)` in your controller to avoid memory leak

Comment: If I used $rootScope would I need the factory?

Comment: keeping variables inside $rootScope and broadcasting an event is different, you do need some kind of service/factory for variable storage (where you can also update them)

Comment: That's what my current factory is doing.